# Joining dfs horizontaly with different axis output Nan values on one of the df values

Tags: pandas

I have a `df1`:

```
     X  Y
ABS  5  6
```

Then I have a different `df2`:

```
     J 
XYJ  7
```

I would simply want to join horizontally both dfs to obtain the following dfs maintaining `df1` index :

```
     X  Y  J
ABS  5  6  7
```

However, when I do:

```
rdo=pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=1,join_axes=[df1.index])
print(rdo)
```

Outputs:

```
     X  Y  J
ABS  5  6  NaN
```

Any idea of an alternative way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need same index values in both `DataFrame`s, simpliest is assign index for same, but necessary same length of both `DataFrame`s:

```
df2.index = df1.index
print (df2)
     J
ABS  7

rdo=pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=1)
print (rdo)
     X  Y  J
ABS  5  6  7
```

Another approach is join by default indices by [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) and then [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html), [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) is for remove index name:

```
rdo= (pd.concat([df1.reset_index(),
               df2.reset_index(drop=True)],axis=1)
        .set_index('index')
        .rename_axis(None))
print (rdo)
     X  Y  J
ABS  5  6  7
```

Detail:

```
print (df1.reset_index())
  index  X  Y
0   ABS  5  6

print (df2.reset_index(drop=True))
   J
0  7
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer